# How can I make a curved wall thicker?

Tags: mesh

How can I make the wall evenly thicker in the direction of the arrows ?

[image]

Comment: if you use Extrude Faces Along Normals it should have equal thickness. If 'you've already extruded and the thickness is not equal you need to correct visually I guess

Comment: @moonboots _Extrude Faces Along Normals_ left at the default tool settings will not offset even and in this case leave you with internal faces afterwards.

Comment: I meant he should have done it this way at the beginning   ;)

Comment: @moonboots Depends on how the wall was created... looks more like there was an edge loop on the top and the thin faces were extruded upwards. Extruding along face normals would have made no thicker wall then.

Comment: I didn't know the Dissolve Orthogal Edges, nice trick

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the inner faces, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normals*.

   [image: extrude faces along normals]
2. While extruding, press <kbd>S</kbd> once to toggle even thickness ON (<kbd>Alt</kbd> needs to be held constantly so I prefer <kbd>S</kbd>).

   [image: even thickness on]
3. After confirming the extrusion with left-clicking, go to the tool options in the bottom left of the viewport and enable *Dissolve Orthogonal Edges*. If you don't, you will end up with inner faces. By the way, here you can enable *Offset Even* afterwards as well if you forgot to do it while extruding.

   [image: dissolve orthogonal edges]
4. If you want to get rid of the edge between the "old" and "new" wall, select it and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Edges*.

   [image: dissolve edges]

Comment: That works, thank you !

Comment: @MIck Please read: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)